# iTunes XML Parsing in cocoa

Tags: cocoa

I am developing an application in cocoa .I need to parse a iTunes XML file of large size(about 25Mb).I am using the following code snippet now
      NSDictionary *itunesDatabase = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:itunesPath];
But this is a little bit slow
Is there any faster method to load the entire data to a dictionary??

Comment: Do you really need to make this faster, or is the problem more that the main thread is blocked while the file is loaded?

Answer (score 3):

The reason you're having such slow performance is because `NSDictionary` reads everything into memory all at once. For a large iTunes library, this can take a long time and -- feel free to confirm this with Activity Monitor -- a metric assload of memory. (This is the precise technical term for that amount of memory)

The alternative in these situations is to use a callback-based XML parser (generally known as "SAX" parsers). These parse XML documents an entity at a time and call your callback methods. In Cocoa, the `NSXMLParser` class provides this functionality. You set your class as its delegate, call the `parse` method, and the parser starts calls the delegate methods as it reads tags, attributes, text, etc. in the XML file.

Now, this is obviously harder than just loading everything into an `NSDictionary` and walking the resulting tree of objects. You'll need to keep track of state information yourself. And you'll have to "build up" your objects progressively, so organizing your classes can be difficult.

However, you can ignore the XML you aren't interested in, and that saves a lot of memory. And, depending on what data you're getting out of iTunes, you may also be able to end the parsing as soon as you've gotten the data you need. Even if this does end up taking quite a while, at least you'll be able to show your user a progress bar or some other indication that your program is working, which is much better than just hanging for 10-20 seconds while `NSDictionary` loads a giant XML file.

Comment: Note that NSXMLParser still reads everything into memory all at once, since `initWithData:` is its designated initializer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to use third-party frameworks, run, do not walk to [EyeTunes](http://code.google.com/p/eyetunes/). (BSD license.) It's an abstraction layer around Apple Events for communicating with iTunes, and as such it doesn't parse the XML database directly (I think, it's been a while since I've used it), but you'll have get/set access to anything in the XML.

Comment: If it's using apple events, the obvious downside is iTunes has to be running to use it

Answer (score 0):

Try to use libxml:

http://www.cimgf.com/2008/08/18/cocoa-tutorial-libxml-and-xmlreader/

To minimize highest memory footprint, create and drain NSAutoreleasePool in your loop